# What's the best practice of Spring/Spring boot chained bean instantiation?

Tags: java, spring-boot

In Spring/Spring boot, which instantiation strategy of the two below is better?

**First:**

```
@Component
Class ServiceA{
  ServiceB b;
  public ServiceA(ServiceB b) {
    this.b = b;
  }
}
```

where ServiceB is also `@Component`.

**Second:**

```
@Component
Class ServiceA{
  ServiceB b;
  public ServiceA() {
    this.b = new ServiceB();
  }
}
```

where ServiceB is a regular class without the spring annotation.

From what I know, Spring instantiates only one instance of `@Component` class as a singleton. So if I understand correctly, the two strategies both instantiate only one instance of ServiceA and ServiceB (in method 2, the `new ServiceB()` has been called only once since there is only one instance of ServiceA).

I had used the first strategy for my previous application, but recently I found that the second strategy facilitates writing test cases since I do not need to load the spring context(or instantiate all chained components manually to create a parent component) therefore the testing is much faster.

Comment: You can also use `@Autowired` annotation on `ServiceB` object in `ServiceA` class to and let spring handle the injection. This way you would need changes to your constructor if you need to add more dependencies. Of the two strategies presented by you, strategy #1 is better from maintenance perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the two strategies both instantiate only one instance of ServiceA and ServiceB

Correct, as long as that code is the entire code, but ...

If you later on have a `ServiceC` that also wants to use `ServiceB`, the second strategy cannot reuse the `ServiceB` singleton. First strategy works without having to refactor the code.

**Use first strategy.**

---

> I found that the second strategy facilitates writing test cases

Wrong. Second strategy *precludes* writing **unit** tests, because you cannot instantiate `ServiceA` with a mock `ServiceB` implementation for testing *only* the `ServiceA` code, i.e. the "unit".

With second strategy, an error in `ServiceB` code will make `ServiceA` look flawed, even though `ServiceA` is perfect.

**Use first strategy.**

Comment: So basically it's my testing strategy wrong. I should just mock nested components and test one layer a time, right?